# Failed to connect to git repository after upgrade to Jenkins 2.332.1 with Git Source Code Management

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Upgraded Jenkins to 2.332.1 and a few plugins to try to stay up to date. Now getting the following error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command “/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h git-repo-link HEAD” returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have no problem cloning the repo from command line. I have tried deleting the workspace, downgrading a few of the plugins, adding the Wipe out repository & force clone in Additional Behaviors under Source Code Management, and a few others.

I can connect to my repo without problem from command line by cloning and/or running ssh -T git@repo-url

Credentials Plugin v2.6.1
Git Plugin v4.11.0
Git Client Plugin v3.11.0
GIT Server Plugin v1.10

Any help besides working through hours of manually downgrades is greatly appreciated

Comment: Cross posted same question here: https://community.jenkins.io/t/failed-to-connect-to-git-repository-after-upgrade-to-jenkins-2-332-1-with-git-source-code-management/1986/2

Comment: This is an ssh issue: Git literally runs ssh to connect to another Git via `ssh://site.name/path/to/repo.git`, and that ssh command has to actually work. Yours isn't, for some ssh reason. To debug this, run ssh (only, if possible, not via Git, although you can do it via Git with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`) with debug options (`-v`, as many `-v` as needed to get the level high enough to get useful diagnostics).

Comment: I will need to try to see how I can get `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to work in a jenkins job. I have no problem running and connecting to my repo successfully running `ssh -T git@repo-url` from the command line

Comment: Have now also tried opening a bug report here: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-68177

Comment: You could also perhaps use `git config` to set `core.sshCommand` to `ssh -v` for debug purposes. That might be easier than messing with Jenkins (I don't really know, I have *used* Jenkins but never tried to get deep into it as it's clearly a horrible program inside: it does terrible things to the Unix signal setup for instance ... if I had my way, Jenkins would cease to exist :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of GIT_SSH_COMMAND, you can make a simple job or pipeline, without any SCM component (nothing to clone), with a single step

```
sh "ssh -Tv git@repoServer"
```

That way, you can check which user and keys are used by Jenkins, and see if anything has changed.

Comment: I have been doing that and it shows that it is finding and using the same key that I get success with when running the command from the command line. This is what has been so confusing and frustrating for me! 

From command line the key is accepted but from an execute shell in a script I end up getting the following error: `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Comment: @DappleZapple Is the Jenkins controller (master) running on a different server, for which SSH egress might be closed?

Comment: No, we unfortunately dont have distributed builds setup. Everything is running on this server

Comment: @DappleZapple Is Jenkins running with the same account you are using to manually test your SSH connection?

Comment: I ssh in using the same username I use to login to the jenkins UI. Not sure if that is what you mean. I believe the jenkins user runs and executes all of our builds.

Comment: @DappleZapple I meant: is the process running Jenkins (java -jar jenkins.war) is owned by the same user you are logged in yourself?

Comment: I believe the process running jenkins is owned by jenkins (or we use sudo yum update jenkins) to update.

When I login to the UI I login as my username to run builds but when I ssh in I change users to be the jenkins user in order to test ssh connections. Hopefully that helps answer your question a little more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243526/discussion-between-vonc-and-dapplezapple).